# pygame camera initialization fails with NotImplementedError

Tags: python, camera, pygame

On a Linux computer with pygame 1.9.3 I am puzzled by the implementation of the initialization of the pygame camera. The code below demonstrates the surprising behavior: In the first call to Camera (`pygame.camera.Camera`) the camera will be initialized, while the second call (`Camera`) raises a `NotImplementedError`.

```
>>> from pygame.camera import Camera, init as camera_init
>>> import pygame.camera
>>> 
>>> camera_init()
>>> camera = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0")
>>> camera = Camera("/dev/video0")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygame/camera.py", line 102, in __init__
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

It must arise from the `Camera` class being declared a global variable and redefined to point to the actual implementation in the `camera.py` file. The first call uses the redefined variable while the second uses the original `Camera` class.

It strikes me as an surprising implementation that may take some time to debug. Could this not be implemented under a factory pattern?

Comment: it is very old module and camera module is only experimental (see documentation) so don't expect too much. See source code and you see that `Camera` use some elements from `pygame.camera` which you didn't import so probably it can't find them (they are in different namespace) and this is why it get error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think many of us have used this part of the pygame library. Therefore, it is unlikely to get an answer on this. However, I agree with what furas mentioned. The module is very old and experimental which can cause a lot of problems and hassle.